# audacity fails .aac output using ffmpeg native encoder 2.2.2 can you tell me why?

Tags: ffmpeg, audacity

Multiple frames in a packet from stream 0
[pcm_f32le @ 008071c0] Invalid PCM packet, data has size 16 but at least a size of 24 was expected
Error while decoding stream #0:0: Invalid data found when processing input
size=  143298kB time=00:25:52.46 bitrate= 756.1kbits/s
size=  143301kB time=00:25:52.51 bitrate= 756.1kbits/s

video:0kB audio:142803kB subtitle:0 data:0 global headers:0kB muxing overhead 0.348368%

this came before:
ffmpeg -i -  -strict experimental -c:a aac -q:a 10

ffmpeg version 2.2.2 Copyright (c) 2000-2014 the FFmpeg developers
built on May 22 2014 19:56:44 with gcc 4.8.2 (GCC)
configuration: --disable-static --enable-shared --enable-gpl --enable-version3 --disable-w32threads --enable-avisynth --enable-bzlib --enable-fontconfig --enable-frei0r --enable-gnutls --enable-iconv --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libcaca --enable-libfreetype --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libilbc --enable-libmodplug --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopus --enable-librtmp --enable-libschroedinger --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvidstab --enable-libvo-aacenc --enable-libvo-amrwbenc --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxavs --enable-libxvid --enable-decklink --enable-zlib
libavutil      52. 66.100 / 52. 66.100
libavcodec     55. 52.102 / 55. 52.102
libavformat    55. 33.100 / 55. 33.100
libavdevice    55. 10.100 / 55. 10.100
libavfilter     4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
libswscale      2.  5.102 /  2.  5.102
libswresample   0. 18.100 /  0. 18.100
libpostproc    52.  3.100 / 52.  3.100
Guessed Channel Layout for  Input Stream #0.0 : 5.1
Input #0, wav, from 'pipe:':
Duration: N/A, bitrate: 9216 kb/s
Stream #0:0: Audio: pcm_f32le ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, 5.1, flt, 9216 kb/s
Output #0, adts, to 'C:\Users\Carol\Documents\Don\Tenet.aac':
Metadata:
encoder         : Lavf55.33.100
Stream #0:0: Audio: aac, 48000 Hz, 5.1, fltp, 128 kb/s
Stream mapping:
Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (pcm_f32le -> aac)
size=      68kB time=00:00:04.03 bitrate= 138.6kbits/s
size=     102kB time=00:00:04.75 bitrate= 175.2kbits/s
size=     255kB time=00:00:07.23 bitrate= 288.7kbits/s
size=     380kB time=00:00:09.13 bitrate= 341.3kbits/s
size=     516kB time=00:00:11.77 bitrate= 358.7kbits/s
size=     609kB time=00:00:13.73 bitrate= 362.9kbits/s
size=     743kB time=00:00:16.40 bitrate= 371.2kbits/s
size=     866kB time=00:00:18.32 bitrate= 387.1kbits/s
size=    1049kB time=00:00:20.92 bitrate= 410.7kbits/s
size=    1239kB time=00:00:22.91 bitrate= 443.0kbits/s
size=    1506kB time=00:00:25.38 bitrate= 486.1kbits/s
size=    1749kB time=00:00:27.54 bitrate= 520.3kbits/s
size=    2011kB time=00:00:29.86 bitrate= 551.7kbits/s
size=    2268kB time=00:00:32.10 bitrate= 578.6kbits/s
size=    2537kB time=00:00:34.38 bitrate= 604.3kbits/s
size=    2797kB time=00:00:36.69 bitrate= 624.4kbits/s
size=    3067kB time=00:00:39.16 bitrate= 641.4kbits/s
size=    3284kB time=00:00:41.30 bitrate= 651.5kbits/s
size=    3505kB time=00:00:43.69 bitrate= 657.2kbits/s
size=    3703kB time=00:00:45.88 bitrate= 661.1kbits/s
size=    3913kB time=00:00:48.29 bitrate= 663.7kbits/s
size=    4106kB time=00:00:50.47 bitrate= 666.5kbits/s
size=    4337kB time=00:00:52.88 bitrate= 671.8kbits/s
size=    4553kB time=00:00:55.18 bitrate= 675.8kbits/s
size=    4811kB time=00:00:57.45 bitrate= 686.0kbits/s
size=    5065kB time=00:00:59.66 bitrate= 695.4kbits/s
size=    5288kB time=00:01:02.22 bitrate= 696.1kbits/s
size=    5502kB time=00:01:04.25 bitrate= 701.4kbits/s
size=    5770kB time=00:01:06.88 bitrate= 706.7kbits/s
size=    5976kB time=00:01:08.86 bitrate= 710.9kbits/s
size=    6195kB time=00:01:11.14 bitrate= 713.3kbits/s
size=    6397kB time=00:01:13.45 bitrate= 713.5kbits/s
size=    6659kB time=00:01:15.86 bitrate= 719.1kbits/s
size=    6889kB time=00:01:18.03 bitrate= 723.1kbits/s
size=    7176kB time=00:01:20.44 bitrate= 730.7kbits/s
size=    7459kB time=00:01:22.75 bitrate= 738.4kbits/s
size=    7725kB time=00:01:25.37 bitrate= 741.2kbits/s
size=    7946kB time=00:01:27.23 bitrate= 746.2kbits/s
size=    8194kB time=00:01:29.60 bitrate= 749.1kbits/s
size=    8384kB time=00:01:31.81 bitrate= 748.0kbits/s
size=    8661kB time=00:01:34.22 bitrate= 753.0kbits/s
size=    8928kB time=00:01:36.42 bitrate= 758.5kbits/s
size=    9186kB time=00:01:38.77 bitrate= 761.9kbits/s
size=    9428kB time=00:01:41.01 bitrate= 764.6kbits/s
size=    9737kB time=00:01:43.61 bitrate= 769.8kbits/s
size=    9912kB time=00:01:45.60 bitrate= 768.9kbits/s
size=   10197kB time=00:01:48.11 bitrate= 772.6kbits/s
size=   10453kB time=00:01:50.20 bitrate= 777.0kbits/s
size=   10732kB time=00:01:52.53 bitrate= 781.2kbits/s
size=   11037kB time=00:01:55.00 bitrate= 786.2kbits/s
size=   11339kB time=00:01:57.41 bitrate= 791.1kbits/s
size=   11586kB time=00:01:59.38 bitrate= 795.0kbits/s
size=   11907kB time=00:02:01.98 bitrate= 799.6kbits/s
size=   12154kB time=00:02:03.98 bitrate= 803.0kbits/s
size=   12444kB time=00:02:06.42 bitrate= 806.4kbits/s
size=   12706kB time=00:02:08.57 bitrate= 809.5kbits/s
size=   13011kB time=00:02:11.02 bitrate= 813.5kbits/s
size=   13277kB time=00:02:13.16 bitrate= 816.8kbits/s
size=   13581kB time=00:02:15.61 bitrate= 820.4kbits/s
size=   13848kB time=00:02:17.77 bitrate= 823.4kbits/s
size=   14161kB time=00:02:20.26 bitrate= 827.1kbits/s
size=   14460kB time=00:02:22.65 bitrate= 830.4kbits/s
size=   14729kB time=00:02:24.85 bitrate= 833.0kbits/s
size=   14964kB time=00:02:26.94 bitrate= 834.2kbits/s
size=   15218kB time=00:02:29.20 bitrate= 835.5kbits/s
size=   15472kB time=00:02:31.48 bitrate= 836.7kbits/s
size=   15612kB time=00:02:32.72 bitrate= 837.4kbits/s
size=   15911kB time=00:02:35.24 bitrate= 839.6kbits/s
size=   16018kB time=00:02:36.13 bitrate= 840.4kbits/s
size=   16297kB time=00:02:38.50 bitrate= 842.3kbits/s
size=   16555kB time=00:02:40.72 bitrate= 843.8kbits/s
size=   16817kB time=00:02:42.92 bitrate= 845.6kbits/s
size=   17077kB time=00:02:45.05 bitrate= 847.6kbits/s
size=   17124kB time=00:02:45.44 bitrate= 847.9kbits/s
size=   17399kB time=00:02:47.61 bitrate= 850.3kbits/s
size=   17684kB time=00:02:49.89 bitrate= 852.7kbits/s
size=   17968kB time=00:02:52.16 bitrate= 855.0kbits/s
size=   18264kB time=00:02:54.50 bitrate= 857.4kbits/s
size=   18573kB time=00:02:56.93 bitrate= 859.9kbits/s
size=   18848kB time=00:02:59.11 bitrate= 862.0kbits/s
size=   19152kB time=00:03:01.50 bitrate= 864.4kbits/s
size=   19431kB time=00:03:03.70 bitrate= 866.5kbits/s
size=   19746kB time=00:03:06.17 bitrate= 868.9kbits/s
size=   20015kB time=00:03:08.28 bitrate= 870.8kbits/s
size=   20316kB time=00:03:10.67 bitrate= 872.8kbits/s
size=   20598kB time=00:03:12.89 bitrate= 874.7kbits/s
size=   20893kB time=00:03:15.24 bitrate= 876.6kbits/s
size=   21129kB time=00:03:17.48 bitrate= 876.5kbits/s
size=   21363kB time=00:03:19.89 bitrate= 875.5kbits/s
size=   21580kB time=00:03:22.15 bitrate= 874.5kbits/s
size=   21810kB time=00:03:24.52 bitrate= 873.6kbits/s
size=   22040kB time=00:03:26.67 bitrate= 873.6kbits/s
size=   22305kB time=00:03:28.89 bitrate= 874.7kbits/s
size=   22600kB time=00:03:31.26 bitrate= 876.3kbits/s
size=   22894kB time=00:03:33.69 bitrate= 877.6kbits/s
size=   23144kB time=00:03:35.85 bitrate= 878.4kbits/s
size=   23417kB time=00:03:38.15 bitrate= 879.4kbits/s
size=   23706kB time=00:03:40.45 bitrate= 880.9kbits/s
size=   24015kB time=00:03:42.91 bitrate= 882.6kbits/s
size=   24281kB time=00:03:45.04 bitrate= 883.9kbits/s
size=   24579kB time=00:03:47.39 bitrate= 885.5kbits/s
size=   24873kB time=00:03:49.71 bitrate= 887.0kbits/s
size=   25152kB time=00:03:52.08 bitrate= 887.8kbits/s
size=   25416kB time=00:03:54.24 bitrate= 888.9kbits/s
size=   25697kB time=00:03:56.56 bitrate= 889.9kbits/s
size=   25980kB time=00:03:58.82 bitrate= 891.2kbits/s
size=   26282kB time=00:04:01.21 bitrate= 892.6kbits/s
size=   26562kB time=00:04:03.41 bitrate= 893.9kbits/s
size=   26821kB time=00:04:05.61 bitrate= 894.6kbits/s
size=   27097kB time=00:04:07.89 bitrate= 895.5kbits/s
size=   27227kB time=00:04:08.93 bitrate= 896.0kbits/s
size=   27533kB time=00:04:11.41 bitrate= 897.1kbits/s
size=   27684kB time=00:04:12.60 bitrate= 897.8kbits/s
size=   27994kB time=00:04:15.06 bitrate= 899.1kbits/s
size=   28291kB time=00:04:17.40 bitrate= 900.4kbits/s
size=   28622kB time=00:04:20.03 bitrate= 901.7kbits/s
size=   28846kB time=00:04:21.80 bitrate= 902.6kbits/s
size=   29159kB time=00:04:24.27 bitrate= 903.9kbits/s
size=   29426kB time=00:04:26.38 bitrate= 904.9kbits/s
size=   29738kB time=00:04:28.86 bitrate= 906.1kbits/s
size=   29992kB time=00:04:30.97 bitrate= 906.7kbits/s
size=   30253kB time=00:04:33.19 bitrate= 907.2kbits/s
size=   30510kB time=00:04:35.39 bitrate= 907.6kbits/s
size=   30533kB time=00:04:35.58 bitrate= 907.6kbits/s
size=   30808kB time=00:04:37.80 bitrate= 908.5kbits/s
size=   31093kB time=00:04:40.10 bitrate= 909.4kbits/s
size=   31251kB time=00:04:41.34 bitrate= 909.9kbits/s
size=   31568kB time=00:04:43.81 bitrate= 911.2kbits/s
size=   31838kB time=00:04:45.93 bitrate= 912.2kbits/s
size=   32149kB time=00:04:48.36 bitrate= 913.3kbits/s
size=   32278kB time=00:04:49.36 bitrate= 913.8kbits/s
size=   32568kB time=00:04:51.62 bitrate= 914.9kbits/s
size=   32865kB time=00:04:53.95 bitrate= 915.9kbits/s
size=   33173kB time=00:04:56.36 bitrate= 917.0kbits/s
size=   33452kB time=00:04:58.53 bitrate= 917.9kbits/s
size=   33762kB time=00:05:00.97 bitrate= 918.9kbits/s
size=   34039kB time=00:05:03.14 bitrate= 919.9kbits/s
size=   34338kB time=00:05:05.47 bitrate= 920.9kbits/s
size=   34626kB time=00:05:07.73 bitrate= 921.8kbits/s
size=   34944kB time=00:05:10.22 bitrate= 922.8kbits/s
size=   35211kB time=00:05:12.32 bitrate= 923.6kbits/s
size=   35509kB time=00:05:14.73 bitrate= 924.3kbits/s
size=   35765kB time=00:05:17.14 bitrate= 923.8kbits/s
size=   36012kB time=00:05:19.55 bitrate= 923.2kbits/s
size=   36218kB time=00:05:21.51 bitrate= 922.8kbits/s
size=   36457kB time=00:05:23.88 bitrate= 922.1kbits/s
size=   36694kB time=00:05:26.10 bitrate= 921.8kbits/s
size=   36930kB time=00:05:28.40 bitrate= 921.2kbits/s
size=   37170kB time=00:05:30.70 bitrate= 920.7kbits/s
size=   37418kB time=00:05:33.03 bitrate= 920.4kbits/s
size=   37680kB time=00:05:35.29 bitrate= 920.6kbits/s
size=   37979kB time=00:05:37.68 bitrate= 921.3kbits/s
size=   38254kB time=00:05:39.88 bitrate= 922.0kbits/s
size=   38564kB time=00:05:42.35 bitrate= 922.8kbits/s
size=   38858kB time=00:05:44.70 bitrate= 923.5kbits/s
size=   39151kB time=00:05:47.02 bitrate= 924.2kbits/s
size=   39411kB time=00:05:49.07 bitrate= 924.9kbits/s
size=   39702kB time=00:05:51.38 bitrate= 925.6kbits/s
size=   39990kB time=00:05:53.66 bitrate= 926.3kbits/s
size=   40297kB time=00:05:56.09 bitrate= 927.0kbits/s
size=   40573kB time=00:05:58.27 bitrate= 927.7kbits/s
size=   40848kB time=00:06:00.64 bitrate= 927.9kbits/s
size=   41070kB time=00:06:02.85 bitrate= 927.2kbits/s
size=   41300kB time=00:06:05.05 bitrate= 926.8kbits/s
size=   41523kB time=00:06:07.44 bitrate= 925.7kbits/s
size=   41620kB time=00:06:08.42 bitrate= 925.4kbits/s
size=   41871kB time=00:06:10.77 bitrate= 925.1kbits/s
size=   42113kB time=00:06:12.97 bitrate= 925.0kbits/s
size=   42342kB time=00:06:15.31 bitrate= 924.2kbits/s
size=   42506kB time=00:06:16.64 bitrate= 924.5kbits/s
size=   42813kB time=00:06:19.07 bitrate= 925.2kbits/s
size=   43084kB time=00:06:21.22 bitrate= 925.8kbits/s
size=   43396kB time=00:06:23.70 bitrate= 926.5kbits/s
size=   43665kB time=00:06:25.83 bitrate= 927.1kbits/s
size=   43985kB time=00:06:28.37 bitrate= 927.8kbits/s
size=   44244kB time=00:06:30.42 bitrate= 928.3kbits/s
size=   44532kB time=00:06:32.83 bitrate= 928.7kbits/s
size=   44802kB time=00:06:35.00 bitrate= 929.1kbits/s
size=   45088kB time=00:06:37.33 bitrate= 929.6kbits/s
size=   45325kB time=00:06:39.61 bitrate= 929.1kbits/s
size=   45539kB time=00:06:42.17 bitrate= 927.6kbits/s
size=   45764kB time=00:06:44.48 bitrate= 926.9kbits/s
size=   45998kB time=00:06:46.97 bitrate= 925.9kbits/s
size=   46177kB time=00:06:48.78 bitrate= 925.4kbits/s
size=   46438kB time=00:06:51.26 bitrate= 925.0kbits/s
size=   46687kB time=00:06:53.39 bitrate= 925.2kbits/s
size=   46982kB time=00:06:55.80 bitrate= 925.6kbits/s
size=   47249kB time=00:06:57.98 bitrate= 926.0kbits/s
size=   47528kB time=00:07:00.30 bitrate= 926.3kbits/s
size=   47799kB time=00:07:02.57 bitrate= 926.6kbits/s
size=   48118kB time=00:07:05.08 bitrate= 927.3kbits/s
size=   48384kB time=00:07:07.17 bitrate= 927.9kbits/s
size=   48710kB time=00:07:09.76 bitrate= 928.5kbits/s
size=   48982kB time=00:07:11.95 bitrate= 928.9kbits/s
size=   49272kB time=00:07:14.47 bitrate= 929.0kbits/s
size=   49498kB time=00:07:16.35 bitrate= 929.3kbits/s
size=   49790kB time=00:07:18.69 bitrate= 929.7kbits/s
size=   50052kB time=00:07:20.96 bitrate= 929.9kbits/s
size=   50337kB time=00:07:23.28 bitrate= 930.2kbits/s
size=   50611kB time=00:07:25.54 bitrate= 930.6kbits/s
size=   50918kB time=00:07:28.00 bitrate= 931.1kbits/s
size=   51184kB time=00:07:30.13 bitrate= 931.5kbits/s
size=   51485kB time=00:07:32.48 bitrate= 932.1kbits/s
size=   51773kB time=00:07:34.74 bitrate= 932.7kbits/s
size=   52072kB time=00:07:37.10 bitrate= 933.2kbits/s
size=   52362kB time=00:07:39.47 bitrate= 933.6kbits/s
size=   52672kB time=00:07:41.97 bitrate= 934.0kbits/s
size=   52918kB time=00:07:43.91 bitrate= 934.4kbits/s
size=   53217kB time=00:07:46.26 bitrate= 935.0kbits/s
size=   53508kB time=00:07:48.52 bitrate= 935.6kbits/s
size=   53825kB time=00:07:50.99 bitrate= 936.2kbits/s
size=   54084kB time=00:07:53.10 bitrate= 936.5kbits/s
size=   54359kB time=00:07:55.43 bitrate= 936.6kbits/s
size=   54629kB time=00:07:57.69 bitrate= 936.8kbits/s
size=   54894kB time=00:07:59.87 bitrate= 937.1kbits/s
size=   55169kB time=00:08:02.26 bitrate= 937.1kbits/s
size=   55293kB time=00:08:03.34 bitrate= 937.1kbits/s
size=   55559kB time=00:08:05.61 bitrate= 937.2kbits/s
size=   55709kB time=00:08:06.89 bitrate= 937.3kbits/s
size=   55979kB time=00:08:09.17 bitrate= 937.5kbits/s
size=   56249kB time=00:08:11.47 bitrate= 937.6kbits/s
size=   56539kB time=00:08:13.78 bitrate= 938.0kbits/s
size=   56822kB time=00:08:16.06 bitrate= 938.4kbits/s
size=   56949kB time=00:08:17.08 bitrate= 938.5kbits/s
size=   57225kB time=00:08:19.34 bitrate= 938.8kbits/s
size=   57385kB time=00:08:20.67 bitrate= 938.9kbits/s
size=   57667kB time=00:08:22.97 bitrate= 939.2kbits/s
size=   57923kB time=00:08:25.08 bitrate= 939.5kbits/s
size=   57988kB time=00:08:25.62 bitrate= 939.5kbits/s
size=   58256kB time=00:08:27.88 bitrate= 939.6kbits/s
size=   58485kB time=00:08:29.86 bitrate= 939.7kbits/s
size=   58780kB time=00:08:32.19 bitrate= 940.1kbits/s
size=   59071kB time=00:08:34.45 bitrate= 940.6kbits/s
size=   59411kB time=00:08:37.09 bitrate= 941.2kbits/s
size=   59722kB time=00:08:39.50 bitrate= 941.7kbits/s
size=   60034kB time=00:08:41.92 bitrate= 942.3kbits/s
size=   60234kB time=00:08:43.64 bitrate= 942.3kbits/s
size=   60487kB time=00:08:46.01 bitrate= 942.0kbits/s
size=   60682kB time=00:08:48.23 bitrate= 941.1kbits/s
size=   60872kB time=00:08:50.68 bitrate= 939.7kbits/s
size=   61058kB time=00:08:52.82 bitrate= 938.7kbits/s
size=   61269kB time=00:08:55.31 bitrate= 937.6kbits/s
size=   61451kB time=00:08:57.42 bitrate= 936.7kbits/s
size=   61658kB time=00:08:59.86 bitrate= 935.6kbits/s
size=   61841kB time=00:09:02.01 bitrate= 934.7kbits/s
size=   62046kB time=00:09:04.34 bitrate= 933.7kbits/s
size=   62238kB time=00:09:06.83 bitrate= 932.4kbits/s
size=   62445kB time=00:09:09.41 bitrate= 931.1kbits/s
size=   62586kB time=00:09:11.21 bitrate= 930.1kbits/s
size=   62787kB time=00:09:13.74 bitrate= 928.8kbits/s
size=   62954kB time=00:09:15.79 bitrate= 927.9kbits/s
size=   63176kB time=00:09:18.44 bitrate= 926.8kbits/s
size=   63338kB time=00:09:20.38 bitrate= 925.9kbits/s
size=   63553kB time=00:09:22.94 bitrate= 924.8kbits/s
size=   63722kB time=00:09:24.99 bitrate= 923.9kbits/s
size=   63924kB time=00:09:27.50 bitrate= 922.7kbits/s
size=   64093kB time=00:09:29.57 bitrate= 921.8kbits/s
size=   64301kB time=00:09:32.18 bitrate= 920.6kbits/s
size=   64496kB time=00:09:34.59 bitrate= 919.5kbits/s
size=   64700kB time=00:09:37.25 bitrate= 918.2kbits/s
size=   64814kB time=00:09:38.77 bitrate= 917.4kbits/s
size=   65084kB time=00:09:41.35 bitrate= 917.1kbits/s
size=   65285kB time=00:09:43.36 bitrate= 916.8kbits/s
size=   65544kB time=00:09:46.02 bitrate= 916.2kbits/s
size=   65737kB time=00:09:47.94 bitrate= 915.9kbits/s
size=   65978kB time=00:09:50.57 bitrate= 915.2kbits/s
size=   66172kB time=00:09:52.55 bitrate= 914.8kbits/s
size=   66448kB time=00:09:55.26 bitrate= 914.5kbits/s
size=   66627kB time=00:09:57.14 bitrate= 914.0kbits/s
size=   66895kB time=00:09:59.76 bitrate= 913.7kbits/s
size=   67075kB time=00:10:01.72 bitrate= 913.2kbits/s
size=   67337kB time=00:10:04.37 bitrate= 912.7kbits/s
size=   67573kB time=00:10:06.82 bitrate= 912.2kbits/s
size=   67830kB time=00:10:09.55 bitrate= 911.6kbits/s
size=   67971kB time=00:10:10.92 bitrate= 911.4kbits/s
size=   68226kB time=00:10:13.58 bitrate= 910.9kbits/s
size=   68413kB time=00:10:15.50 bitrate= 910.5kbits/s
size=   68662kB time=00:10:18.15 bitrate= 909.9kbits/s
size=   68853kB time=00:10:20.11 bitrate= 909.6kbits/s
size=   69101kB time=00:10:22.74 bitrate= 909.0kbits/s
size=   69281kB time=00:10:24.70 bitrate= 908.5kbits/s
size=   69531kB time=00:10:27.32 bitrate= 908.0kbits/s
size=   69708kB time=00:10:29.29 bitrate= 907.4kbits/s
size=   69970kB time=00:10:31.97 bitrate= 907.0kbits/s
size=   70212kB time=00:10:34.47 bitrate= 906.5kbits/s
size=   70465kB time=00:10:37.18 bitrate= 905.9kbits/s
size=   70589kB time=00:10:38.48 bitrate= 905.7kbits/s
size=   70838kB time=00:10:41.08 bitrate= 905.2kbits/s
size=   71027kB time=00:10:43.07 bitrate= 904.8kbits/s
size=   71279kB time=00:10:45.63 bitrate= 904.4kbits/s
size=   71493kB time=00:10:47.68 bitrate= 904.3kbits/s
size=   71724kB time=00:10:50.06 bitrate= 903.8kbits/s
size=   71933kB time=00:10:52.26 bitrate= 903.4kbits/s
size=   72168kB time=00:10:54.72 bitrate= 903.0kbits/s
size=   72361kB time=00:10:56.85 bitrate= 902.5kbits/s
size=   72586kB time=00:10:59.17 bitrate= 902.1kbits/s
size=   72801kB time=00:11:01.46 bitrate= 901.6kbits/s
size=   73028kB time=00:11:03.82 bitrate= 901.2kbits/s
size=   73245kB time=00:11:06.04 bitrate= 900.9kbits/s
size=   73461kB time=00:11:08.30 bitrate= 900.5kbits/s
size=   73691kB time=00:11:10.63 bitrate= 900.2kbits/s
size=   73760kB time=00:11:11.33 bitrate= 900.1kbits/s
size=   73982kB time=00:11:13.64 bitrate= 899.7kbits/s
size=   74133kB time=00:11:15.24 bitrate= 899.4kbits/s
size=   74359kB time=00:11:17.56 bitrate= 899.0kbits/s
size=   74579kB time=00:11:19.82 bitrate= 898.7kbits/s
size=   74820kB time=00:11:22.24 bitrate= 898.4kbits/s
size=   75022kB time=00:11:24.41 bitrate= 898.0kbits/s
size=   75232kB time=00:11:26.78 bitrate= 897.4kbits/s
size=   75431kB time=00:11:29.02 bitrate= 896.8kbits/s
size=   75631kB time=00:11:31.32 bitrate= 896.2kbits/s
size=   75825kB time=00:11:33.61 bitrate= 895.5kbits/s
size=   76036kB time=00:11:36.02 bitrate= 894.9kbits/s
size=   76222kB time=00:11:38.19 bitrate= 894.3kbits/s
size=   76434kB time=00:11:40.62 bitrate= 893.7kbits/s
size=   76626kB time=00:11:42.80 bitrate= 893.2kbits/s
size=   76831kB time=00:11:45.19 bitrate= 892.5kbits/s
size=   77013kB time=00:11:47.39 bitrate= 891.9kbits/s
size=   77199kB time=00:11:49.69 bitrate= 891.1kbits/s
size=   77375kB time=00:11:51.97 bitrate= 890.3kbits/s
size=   77567kB time=00:11:54.34 bitrate= 889.5kbits/s
size=   77738kB time=00:11:56.58 bitrate= 888.7kbits/s
size=   77916kB time=00:11:58.86 bitrate= 887.9kbits/s
size=   78106kB time=00:12:01.17 bitrate= 887.2kbits/s
size=   78325kB time=00:12:03.73 bitrate= 886.6kbits/s
size=   78500kB time=00:12:05.76 bitrate= 886.1kbits/s
size=   78723kB time=00:12:08.17 bitrate= 885.6kbits/s
size=   78930kB time=00:12:10.36 bitrate= 885.3kbits/s
size=   79155kB time=00:12:12.67 bitrate= 885.0kbits/s
size=   79383kB time=00:12:14.95 bitrate= 884.8kbits/s
size=   79618kB time=00:12:17.19 bitrate= 884.7kbits/s
size=   79852kB time=00:12:19.52 bitrate= 884.6kbits/s
size=   79916kB time=00:12:20.18 bitrate= 884.5kbits/s
size=   80151kB time=00:12:22.54 bitrate= 884.2kbits/s
size=   80320kB time=00:12:24.14 bitrate= 884.2kbits/s
size=   80570kB time=00:12:26.36 bitrate= 884.3kbits/s
size=   80822kB time=00:12:28.65 bitrate= 884.4kbits/s
size=   81049kB time=00:12:30.72 bitrate= 884.4kbits/s
size=   81305kB time=00:12:32.98 bitrate= 884.6kbits/s
size=   81344kB time=00:12:33.32 bitrate= 884.6kbits/s
size=   81614kB time=00:12:35.56 bitrate= 884.9kbits/s
size=   81903kB time=00:12:37.86 bitrate= 885.3kbits/s
size=   82038kB time=00:12:38.99 bitrate= 885.4kbits/s
size=   82295kB time=00:12:41.06 bitrate= 885.8kbits/s
size=   82475kB time=00:12:42.51 bitrate= 886.1kbits/s
size=   82733kB time=00:12:44.65 bitrate= 886.3kbits/s
size=   82994kB time=00:12:46.86 bitrate= 886.6kbits/s
size=   83094kB time=00:12:47.80 bitrate= 886.6kbits/s
size=   83348kB time=00:12:50.00 bitrate= 886.7kbits/s
size=   83553kB time=00:12:51.69 bitrate= 887.0kbits/s
size=   83818kB time=00:12:53.95 bitrate= 887.2kbits/s
size=   84049kB time=00:12:56.21 bitrate= 887.0kbits/s
size=   84273kB time=00:12:58.38 bitrate= 886.9kbits/s
size=   84494kB time=00:13:00.75 bitrate= 886.5kbits/s
size=   84518kB time=00:13:01.05 bitrate= 886.5kbits/s
size=   84684kB time=00:13:03.44 bitrate= 885.5kbits/s
size=   84805kB time=00:13:05.49 bitrate= 884.4kbits/s
size=   84948kB time=00:13:08.22 bitrate= 882.9kbits/s
size=   85013kB time=00:13:10.08 bitrate= 881.5kbits/s
size=   85136kB time=00:13:13.74 bitrate= 878.7kbits/s
size=   85216kB time=00:13:16.18 bitrate= 876.8kbits/s
size=   85339kB time=00:13:19.27 bitrate= 874.7kbits/s
size=   85477kB time=00:13:22.90 bitrate= 872.1kbits/s
size=   85556kB time=00:13:24.88 bitrate= 870.8kbits/s
size=   85687kB time=00:13:28.44 bitrate= 868.3kbits/s
size=   85836kB time=00:13:32.37 bitrate= 865.6kbits/s
size=   85908kB time=00:13:34.31 bitrate= 864.2kbits/s
size=   86025kB time=00:13:37.64 bitrate= 861.9kbits/s
size=   86160kB time=00:13:41.46 bitrate= 859.2kbits/s
size=   86192kB time=00:13:42.40 bitrate= 858.6kbits/s
size=   86329kB time=00:13:45.92 bitrate= 856.3kbits/s
size=   86383kB time=00:13:46.98 bitrate= 855.7kbits/s
size=   86514kB time=00:13:49.80 bitrate= 854.1kbits/s
size=   86598kB time=00:13:51.42 bitrate= 853.2kbits/s
size=   86756kB time=00:13:54.06 bitrate= 852.1kbits/s
size=   86942kB time=00:13:56.48 bitrate= 851.5kbits/s
size=   87111kB time=00:13:59.14 bitrate= 850.4kbits/s
size=   87202kB time=00:14:00.59 bitrate= 849.8kbits/s
size=   87371kB time=00:14:03.20 bitrate= 848.8kbits/s
size=   87496kB time=00:14:05.20 bitrate= 848.0kbits/s
size=   87645kB time=00:14:07.68 bitrate= 847.0kbits/s
size=   87769kB time=00:14:09.79 bitrate= 846.1kbits/s
size=   87973kB time=00:14:12.20 bitrate= 845.7kbits/s
size=   88104kB time=00:14:14.37 bitrate= 844.8kbits/s
size=   88251kB time=00:14:16.93 bitrate= 843.6kbits/s
size=   88370kB time=00:14:18.98 bitrate= 842.8kbits/s
size=   88525kB time=00:14:21.61 bitrate= 841.7kbits/s
size=   88675kB time=00:14:24.10 bitrate= 840.7kbits/s
size=   88836kB time=00:14:26.70 bitrate= 839.7kbits/s
size=   88928kB time=00:14:28.18 bitrate= 839.1kbits/s
size=   89086kB time=00:14:30.80 bitrate= 838.1kbits/s
etc.

Comment: Your ffmpeg is 6 years old. Get a recent version and try again.

Comment: I don't know if Audacity supports the latest version. I think I'll try Adobe Master CS5 if I can figure out that nightmare!

Comment: Audacity supports the latest version.

Comment: When I attempt to export using ffmpeg, audacity wants to look for the avformat.55  which is not available in updated versions from what I've seen. Will the "locate file avformat.55" disappear if I clear all the app data and install newer ffmpeg? I think I tried that but will try anything at this point.